# AngularJS services result returning udefined

Tags: angularjs

I have seen the previously answered question but doesn't seem to help my situation.

I get this error when trying to retrieve the information from the database using angular.

```
angular.js:10071 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Result' of undefined
    at services.js:29
```

I understand that I am trying to redefine a variable. but don't know how to fix it. here is my **services.js** code.

```
(function (){
    //turn strict syntax on
    "use strict";
    angular.module('ContinentApp').
    service('dataService',
    [
        '$q',
            '$http',
            function ($q, $http){
                //create variable to hold the urlBase data
                var urlBase  = '/cm0665-assignment/server/index.php';
                // retrieve promise for the success method to get continents
                this.getContinents = function(){
                    var defer = $q.defer(),
                        data = {
                            action: 'list',
                            subject: 'continents'
                        }; //end of data array object
                    // create an ajax call that chains success and error
                    // which will accept or reject the promise
                    $http.get(urlBase, {params: data, cache: true}).
                    //if successful then get the promise
                    success(function(response){
                        defer.resolve({
                            //create a data property from the values of the response
                            data: response.ResultSet.Result,
                            //create rowCount property from response values
                            rowCount: response.ResultSet.RowCount
                        });//end of defer resolve
                    }).  //end of success response
                    //error function to reject the promise
                    error(function (err){
                        defer.reject(err);
                    }); // end off error function

                    //get the deferred promise
                    return defer.promise;
                }; // end of getContinent

                //function to get the countries from the DB
                // similar to the getContinent function
                this.getCountry = function(A2Code){
                    // create a data array object and store in variable
                    var defer = $q.defer(),
                        data = {
                            action: 'list',
                            subject: 'country',
                            id: A2Code
                        };
                    // create an ajax call that chains success and error
                    // which will accept or reject the promise
                    $http.get(urlBase, {params: data, cache: false}).
                    //if successful then get the promise
                    success(function(response){
                        defer.resolve({
                            //create a data property from the values of the response
                            data: response.ResultSet.Result,
                            //create rowCount property from response values
                            rowCount: response.ResultSet.RowCount
                        });

                    }). // end of function success
                    //error function to reject the promise
                    error(function(err){
                        defer.reject(err);
                    });
                    //get the deferred promise
                    return defer.promise;
                };
                // create function to update country
                //similar toi the two above
                this.updateCountry = function (country) {
                    var defer = $q.defer(),
                        // create data array object
                        data = {
                            action: 'update',
                            subject: 'country',
                            data: angular.toJSON(country)
                        };
                    // create an $http POST so data can be updated
                    $http.post(urlBase, data).
                        success(function(response){
                            defer.reject(response);
                    }).
                        error(function(err){
                            defer.reject(err);
                    });
                    return defer.promise
                };

            } // end of function $q, $http

    ]
). // end of service
service('applicationData',

    function($rootScope){
        var sharedService = {};
        sharedService.info = {};

        sharedService.publishInfo = function (key, obj) {
            this.info[key] =  obj;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('systemInfo_' +key, obj);
        };

        return sharedService;
    }
);//end of service
}());// end of IIFE
```

this a JSONRecordSet file that is connected to it

```
 <?php
 if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost') {
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
     error_reporting(-1); // show all errors
 } else {
    ini_set('display_errors', false);
    error_reporting(0); // show no errors
}
require_once  ('classes/pdoDB.class.php');
abstract class R_RecordSet {
    protected $db;
    protected $stmt;
    function __construct (){
        $this->db = pdoDB::getConnection();
    }
    //using two variables $sql and $params to connect to the recordset and
    // build an optional associative array prepared statement.
    function getRecordSet($sql, $params = null){
        //if recordSet is an array then
        if (is_array($params)){
            //prepare statement to
            // pass the name placeholder and the value it'll have
            $this->stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            // execute the prepared statement
            $this->stmt->execute($params);
        } //end of if
        // query the sql and display the query to show there is an error
        else{
            $this->stmt = $this->db->query($sql);
        }// end of else
       return $this->stmt;
    }// end of function getRecordSet
}//end of recordSet class
// class created to return records as an encoded JSON string
class JSONRecordSet extends R_RecordSet {
    //retrieve the recordSet class so it can be displayed in JSON
    function getRecordSet($sql, $elementName = 'ResultSet', $params = null) 
{
        //store the record set into a variable to create an sql statement 
operand
        $stmt = parent::getRecordSet($sql, $params);
        //fetchAll associated Records via pdo::FETCH_ASSOC
        $recordSet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //store all $record set into a variable which collects however many there are
        $nRecords = count($recordSet);
            //if there are no records then don't return any data
        if ($nRecords == 0){
            //create variables to use in the else statement and the return statement
            $status = 'error';
            $message = array("text" => "No Records Found");
            $result = '[]';
       }
        // else return the data from request stream the return the $recordSet
        else{
            //using the variables created ain the if statement
            $status = 'ok';
            $message = array("text" => "");
            $result = $recordSet;
        }
        // return JSON data in the following order using json_encode
        return json_encode(
            array(
                //using the variables from the if else staments to return the data as JSON
                'status' => $status,
                'message'=> $message,
                "$elementName" =>array(
                    "RowCount" =>$nRecords,
                    "Result" =>$result
                )
            ), //print out in correct json format while checkking the count
            JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
         );//end of json encode
    } // end of getRecordSet
}//end of JSONRecordSet
```

This is my controller file

```
//a page to act as a multi controller
(function(){
    //Tell angular to use strict
    "use strict";
    //build up an index controller to control what is seen on the index.html page
   angular.module('ContinentApp').
   controller('IndexController',
    [
        '$scope',
        'applicationData', //angular variable as a string
         function ($scope, appData) {
             //add a title property which we can refer to in our view (index.html)
             $scope.title = 'Continents and Country list';
             $scope.subtitle = 'Please Select a Continent';
             $scope.ID = '';
             // turning on  a listener for the service $broadcast
             $scope.$on('systemInfo_continent', function(e, continent){
                 $scope.Name = continent.Name;
             });// end of $broadcast listener
         }
    ]
). //end of index controller
//create a continent controller
controller('ContinentController',
    [
        '$scope',
        'dataService',
        'applicationData',
        '$location',
        function ($scope, dataService, appData, $location){

            appData.publishInfo('continents', {});

            var getContinents = function (){
                dataService.getContinents().then(
                    function (response) {
                        $scope.continentCount = response.rowCount + ' continents';
                        $scope.continents = response.data;
                    },
                    function (err){
                        $scope.status = 'unable to load data' + err;
                    },
                    function (notify){
                        console.log(notify);
                    }
                ); //end of then
            }; //end of getContinent
            var continentInfo = $location.path().substr(1).split('/');
            if (continentInfo.length===2){
                // use the ID from the path and assign it to the selected
                //continent so it will remain highlighted after a page reload
                $scope.selectedContinent={ID: continentInfo[1]};
            }
            //return the ID and concatenate the continentInfo
            $scope.selectedContinent = {};
            $scope.selectContinent = function($event, continent){
                $scope.selectedContinent = continent;
                $location.path('/continents/', continent.ID);
                appData.publishInfo('continent', continent)
            };
            // get the continent, as defined above
            getContinents();
        }
    ]
). // end of continent controller
controller('CountryController',
   [
       '$scope',
       'dataService',
       '$routeParams',
       function ($scope, dataService, $routeParams){
            $scope.country = [];
            $scope.countryCount =0;
            var getCountry=function (ID){
                dataService.getCountry(ID).then(
                    function (response){
                        $scope.countryCount=response.rowCount + ' country';
                        $scope.country = response.data;
                    },
                    function (err){
                        $scope.status = 'unable to load data'+err;
                    }
                );// end of then
            };
            //only if a continent ID was passed, then get the countries
           if ($routeParams && $routeParams.ID){
               console.log($routeParams.ID);
               getCountry($routeParams.ID);
           }

           $scope.showEditCountry=function ($event, country, editorID){
               var element = $event.currentTarget,
                   padding = 22,
                   posY    = (element.offsetTop + element.clientTop + padding)-(element.scrollTop + eleementclientTop),
                   studentEditorElement = document.getElementByID(editorID);
               console.log(country);
               $scope.selectedCountry = angular.copy(country);
               $scope.editoeVisible = true;
               countryEditorElement.style.position = 'absolute';
               studentEditorElement.style.top = posY +'px';
           }; //end of showEditCountry
           // abandon the edit process
           $scope.abandonEdit = function (){
               $scope.editorVisible = false;
               $scope.selectedCountry = null;
           }; //end of abandonEdit
           // function to save the edited country data
           $scope.scope.saveCountry = function(){
               var n,
                   cCount = $scope.country.length,
                   currentCountry;
               $scope.editorVisible = false;
               // call the dataService method
               dataService.updateCountry($scope.selectedCountry).then(
                   function (response) {
                       $scope.status = response.status;
                       if (response.status === 'ok'){
                           for (n = 0; n < cCount; n += 1){
                               currentCountry = $scope.country[n];
                               if (currentCountry.countryID === $scope.selectedCountry.countryID){
                                   $scope.country[n] = angular.copy($scope.selectedCountry);
                                   break;
                               }
                           }
                       }
                       console.log(response);
                       // reset selectedCountry
                       $scope.selectedCountry = null;
                   },
                   function (err) {
                       $scope.status = "error with save" + err;
                   }
               );//end of then
           };// end of saveCountry
       } //end of function ($scope, dataService, $routeParams)
   ]
); // end of CountryController
}()); // end of the instantly initiated function and page
```

Comment: Can you please provide `console.log('response', response)` before error occur, on line 28 for example

Comment: Object {status: "error", message: Object}

Comment: So, as you can see, your server responsed with error, insead of `{ResultSet: { ... }}`. What is in error `message`  Object?

Comment: It turned out to be my db connection file path wasn't correct this is why the object was undefined